No Columns found - We reached the end of the buffer Power Query
I've done a number of API pulls through power query and generally they've been relatively easy, however the application I'm trying to pull from doesn't make it easy when there's more than 5k of records. I can either cycle round and pull each new page based on a value passed as part of the JSON or use a different API, which involves posting a request to the API for the particular report to create a dataset, then receiving a dataset ID and using that to then pull the records from the report.
It's been a bit of a battle to get to here as Power Query wants an anonymous POST connection, but that bit works ok.
I've put it all into one query and can get everything back however when I then convert the JSON response to a table, it errors out saying no columns found, even though I can query any record from the list. Previously when I've converted JSON to tables, it's been really easy, but nothing I'm doing seems to work. Any ideas?


let
    jsonBody = "
{
  ""Name"": ""GTN Export"",
  ""Description"": ""TEST"",
  ""XRefCode"": ""GTNExport"",
  ""ReportId"": 5005,
  ""MaxRows"": 20000,
  ""OnlyIncludeUniqueRecords"": true,
  ""Filters"": [
    {
      ""Name"": ""@PRPayRunId"",
      ""Description"": ""@PRPayRunId"",
      ""DataType"": ""Reference"",
      ""Operator"": ""="",
      ""IsRequired"": true,
      ""Value"": ""4963"",
      ""Editable"": true
    },
    {
      ""Name"": ""@CountryCode"",
      ""Description"": ""@CountryCode"",
      ""DataType"": ""String"",
      ""Operator"": ""="",
      ""IsRequired"": true,
      ""Value"": ""GBR"",
      ""Editable"": true
    }

  ]
}    ",
    username = "YYYY",
    password = "XXXX",
    
    authHeader = "Basic " & Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(username & ":" & password), BinaryEncoding.Base64),

    URLL = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="GTNURL"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    postURL = URLL & "Reports/" & Text.From(#"API Report ID"),

    response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(postURL, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json", Authorization=authHeader], Content=Text.ToBinary(jsonBody), ManualStatusHandling={400}])),
    Data = response[Data],
    DatasetId = Data[DatasetId],
    datasetURL = URLL & "Datasets/" & DatasetId,
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(datasetURL, [Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/json", Authorization=authHeader],ManualStatusHandling={400}])),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"



I get records out correctly:


But when I convert to table and then try and expand the columns, it doesn't find the columns and errors with the we reached the end of the buffer.
The report has about 25k of records,


I think you are supposed to use Table. FromRecords(Source) instead of Table.FromList?

Either Table.FromRecords(Source) as suggested by @rachel or Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.Sp... followed by Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", ListOfFieldNames) should work. If they do not, I think we'd need to see a sample of a valid JSON that is causing the problem as text which can be copy/pasted; not a screenshot. (Please replace confidential information with nonsense before posting that.) A valid JSON means just a few records, but  complete JSON, not just the first few lines. Rather a proper heading; the records; and then the ending

Thanks both, That now gets me a list of fields which is great news. I still get the red/white bars, and when I look at the column statistics or value distribution across the first 1000 or whole response it says "We encountered an error while computing the distribution" The data looks legit, doesn't look anything wrong with it.
I'm using = Table.FromRecords(Source,null,MissingField.UseNull)

@Itsallgonepearshaped Unless you can provide a valid JSON we can use to reproduce the problem, I don't think we can help you further. There's some error in an assumption PQ is making about your data.

Thanks @RonRosenfeld. It's employee data so I'm not comfortable in sharing. I think the issue is actually the call now - the data that was returning wasn't actually being returned - it was just cached from a previous run. It's all down to the security model I'm using as PQ doesn't like basic auth with a POST.

@Itsallgonepearshaped Unless the structure itself is confidential, all you need to do is change the data to nonsense. The important thing is that what you present reproduces the problem you are trying to solve. But if you have a solution, then no need.
